# Trimming audio using mp4Parser. Or is there any alternative?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, trim, android-ffmpeg, mp4parser

I am trying to trim an audio using [mp4Parser](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser).
Is that possible?

I tried ffmpeg which is quite time consuming.
Our app does require both video and audio processing.

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg is fast.  What command did you use?  maybe you made ffmpeg transcode, which is slow?

What about

```
 fmpeg -i audiofile.mp3 -ss 3 -t 5 -acodec copy outfile.mp3
```

This remuxes starting from second 3 for 5 seconds into `outfile.mp3`, very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, possible with mp4Parser and FFMPEG also.
You have to use some command key for faster processing in FFMPEG.

You could take a look into this library :

[k4l-video-trimmer](https://github.com/titansgroup/k4l-video-trimmer)

Comment: FFMPEG is so slow.i want to trim audio not video

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible to trim audio with mp4parser.

It should be something like following

```
private CroppedTrack getCroppedTrack(Track track, int startTimeMs, int endTimeMs)
{
    long currentSample = 0;
    double currentTime = 0;
    long startSample = -1;
    long endSample = -1;
    double startTime = startTimeMs / 1000;
    double endTime = endTimeMs / 1000;

    for (int i = 0; i < track.getSampleDurations().length; i++)
    {
        if (currentTime <= startTime)
        {
            // current sample is still before the new starttime
            startSample = currentSample;
        }
        if (currentTime <= endTime) {
            // current sample is after the new start time and still before the new endtime
            endSample = currentSample;
        }
        else
        {
            // current sample is after the end of the cropped video
            break;
        }
        currentTime += (double) track.getSampleDurations()[i] / (double) track.getTrackMetaData().getTimescale();
        currentSample++;
    }

    return new CroppedTrack(track, startSample, endSample);
}
```

Use the above method to trim track/tracks as per your desired start and end points.

```
movie.addTrack(getCroppedTrack(track, 0, 8000));
```